# Как правильно реализовать перемотку песни на javascript?

Tags: javascript, аудио

Я пилю аудио-плеер. Все просто - fastapi+ванильный набор html, css, js.

Когда я сижу в обычном браузере (имею ввиду не в режиме инкогнито, например), то при отключенной функции в devtools  "Отключение кеширования" не могу обновлять страничку с внесенными, например, в файл js изменениями. При входе в режим инкогнито или включении функции "Отключение кеширования" в devtools появляется другая проблема - перестает функционировать изменение значения currentTime песни при перемотки.

Кто решить эту проблему?

```
const music = new Audio();
let isUserInteracted = false;
function check_pause() {
    let masterPlay = document.getElementById('masterPlay');
    if (music.paused || music.currentTime <= 0) {
        music.play()
            .then(() => {
                masterPlay.removeAttribute('icon');
                masterPlay.setAttribute('icon', 'line-md:pause');
                masterPlay.style.marginRight = '10px';
                masterPlay.style.width = '50px';
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error during playback:', error);
            });
    } else {
        music.pause();
        masterPlay.removeAttribute('icon');
        masterPlay.setAttribute('icon', 'line-md:play-filled');
    }
    isUserInteracted = false;
}
seek.addEventListener('change', () => {
    music.currentTime = seek.value * music.duration / 100;
});
function playSong(author_name, song_name, song_filename, username, playlist_id) {
    let songTagName = document.getElementById('song-name');
    songTagName.innerText = song_name;

    if (!music.src) {
        music.src = `/static/songs/playlists/${username}/${playlist_id}/${song_filename}`;
        isUserInteracted = true;
        music.addEventListener('canplaythrough', check_pause(), false);

    } else {
        isUserInteracted = true;
        check_pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: А ошибки консоль выдаёт? Если да, то давайте их проанализируем.

Comment: Ошибок нет, до понимания что когда работает, а что нет, решалось методом тыка буквально